# How to read a big tif file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm loading a tiff file from http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/DOCS/DistFromCoast/

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('GMT_intermediate_coast_distance_01d.tif')
```

The data is large (`im.size=(36000, 18000)` 1.3GB) and conventional conversion doesn't work; i.e, `imarray.shape` returns `()`

```
import numpy as np 
imarray=np.zeros(im.size)
imarray=np.array(im)
```

How can I convert this tiff file to a `numpy.array`?

Comment: `conventional conversion doesn't work` - *how* doesn't it work? What is your output? How does it differ from what you expect? Do you receive an error? If so, what does the traceback say?

Comment: Try [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html).

Comment: @That1Guy `imarray` is an empty array

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit Python?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes it's 64-bits

Comment: Thank you @cgohlke now I can get a `numpy.array` ... It takes a while to load the data

Answer (score 4):

May you dont have too much Ram for this image.You'll need at least some more than 1.3GB free memory.

I don't know what you're doing with the image and you read the entire into your memory but i recommend you to read it bit by bit if its possible to avoid blowing up your computer. 
You can use `Image.getdata()` which returns one pixel per time.

Also read some more for  `Image.open` on this link  :

http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/

Answer (score 3):

So far I have tested many alternatives but only [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) worked always even with huge 16bit images.

You can open an image with something like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
ds = gdal.Open("name.tif")
channel = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
```

Comment: How do I install GDAL to use with python?

Answer (score 2):

I had huge tif files between 1 and 3 GB and managed to finally open them with Image.open() after manually changing the value of MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS inside the Image.py source code to an arbitrarily large number:

```
from PIL import Image
im = np.asarray(Image.open("location/image.tif")
```

Comment: Ugh! Don't do that! Maintenance nightmare! Just change it in your own script with `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None`

Answer (score 1):

For Python 32 bit, version 2.7 you are limited by the number of bytes you can add to the stack at a given time. One option is to read in the image in parts and then resize the individual chunks and reassemble them into a image that requires less RAM.

I recommend using the packages `libtiff` and `opencv` for that.

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin"
import numpy as np
import libtiff
import cv2

tif = libtiff.TIFF.open("HUGETIFFILE.tif", 'r')
width = tif.GetField("ImageWidth")
height = tif.GetField("ImageLength")
bits = tif.GetField('BitsPerSample')
sample_format = tif.GetField('SampleFormat')

ResizeFactor = 10 #Reduce Image Size by 10
Chunks = 8 #Read Image in 8 Chunks to prevent Memory Error (can be increased for 
# bigger files)

ReadStrip = tif.ReadEncodedStrip
typ = tif.get_numpy_type(bits, sample_format)


#ReadStrip
newarr = np.zeros((1, width/ResizeFactor), typ)
for ii in range(0,Chunks):
    pos = 0
    arr = np.empty((height/Chunks, width), typ)
    size = arr.nbytes
    for strip in range((ii*tif.NumberOfStrips()/Chunks),((ii+1)*tif.NumberOfStrips()/Chunks)):
        elem = ReadStrip(strip, arr.ctypes.data + pos, max(size-pos, 0))
        pos = pos + elem

    resized = cv2.resize(arr, (0,0), fx=float(1)/float(ResizeFactor), fy=float(1)/float(ResizeFactor))

    # Now remove the large array to free up Memory for the next chunk
    del arr
    # Finally recombine the individual resized chunks into the final resized image.
    newarr = np.vstack((newarr,resized))

newarr = np.delete(newarr, (0), axis=0)
cv2.imwrite('resized.tif', newarr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use 'dask' library:

```
import dask_image.imread

ds = dask_image.imread.imread('name.tif')
```